# How do you get the user_id of an article in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I'm following L5 Fundamentals, trying to improve on things but it's getting a bit complicated especially that you can do the same thing in many different ways. I keep forgetting which is which.

I am trying to check if the article the user is trying to edit belongs to him, if not, I'll redirect him with a message. I'm applying this to my `edit()` method in `ArticlesController`

I was able to get the `id` of the logged in user but I couldn't get the `user_id` in `articles` so I can compare them.

This is what I have so far, as you can see it's commented as it's not the result I want and this is the closest I got to getting anything out of it.

Also should I implement this condition on the controller or the view? and why?

```
public function edit(Article $article) {
    $user = Auth::id();
    //$articleUserId = $article->user()->getResults();
    dd($user);

    if($user) {
        $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');
        //$article = Article::findOrFail($id);

        return view('blog/edit')->with('article', $article)
            ->with('tags', $tags);
    } else {
        return 'you are not logged in';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function edit(Article $article) {
    if ( ! auth()->check()) {
        return 'you are not logged in';
    }

    if ($article->user_id != auth()->id()) {
        return 'This is not your article';
    }

    $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('blog.edit')->with(compact('article', 'tags'));
}
```

---

I've seen people add an `owns` method to their `User` model:

```php
public function owns(Model $model)
{
    return object_get($model, 'user_id') == $this->id;
}
```

Then in your view, you can check it:

```php
@if (auth()->user()->owns($article))
   // show whatever...
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. It did the job. But now the question, how can I hide the "EDIT" link on the view if the user id of the article is not the same as the user id of the logged in user?

Comment: @Halnex - I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I want to comment in your question but i don't have enough reputation so i will just post another answer..

> Thanks. It did the job. But now the question, how can I hide the
>   "EDIT" link on the view if the user id of the article is not the same
>   as the user id of the logged in user? –  Halnex 8 hours ago

Base on the answer of `Joseph Silber`

in your view..

```
@foreach($article as $value)
 @if($article->user_id == Auth::id())
   //SHOW EDIT BUTTON
 @endif
@endforeach
```